# JavaFX Как сделать окно внутри окна

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

Как на [javafx](/questions/tagged/javafx) сделать окно Window 2 внутри главного окна Window 1? Т.е. Window 2 можно свернуть и развернуть, но внутри Window 1. Как на скрине, который написан на Delphi:

[image: Delphi Forms]

Исходник

**Main.java**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Window 1");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

**Controller.java**

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Controller {


public void showWindow2(ActionEvent event) throws IOException  {

    Stage stage2 = new Stage();
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample2.fxml"));
    stage2.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage2.setTitle("Window 2");
    stage2.initModality(Modality.NONE);
    stage2.show();
}
}
```

**sample.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>


<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" 
      maxWidth="-Infinity" 
      minHeight="-Infinity" 
      minWidth="-Infinity" 
      prefHeight="400.0" 
      prefWidth="600.0"
      xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" 
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
      fx:controller="sample.Controller">
<children>
  <Button 
     fx:id="showWindow" 
     layoutX="29.0" 
     layoutY="25.0" 
     mnemonicParsing="false" 
     onAction="#showWindow2" 
     text="show windows" />
</children> 
</Pane>
```

**sample2.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
        xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
        fx:controller="sample.Controller2"
        prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">

</AnchorPane>
```

Искал по разному Window in Window, Stage in Stage, Scene in Scene, и нашел о этой [ссылке](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/InternalFrameDemoProject/src/components/InternalFrameDemo.java)

Решение в Java Swing, а нужно средствами JavaFX

Comment: например вот: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q-5c1zPFaGY а вообще, MDI-приложения остались в прошлом - сейчас для этого используются либо несколько окон, либо вкладки

Comment: На голой JavaFX без писанины - никак, можно попробовать вот такую [либу](http://jfxtras.org/)

Comment: Alex Chermenin - благодарю за ответ! Отличное видео.

Comment: ezhov_da - благодарю за отклик. А не могли бы вы более конкретнее указать библиотеку и пример её использования. Не очень хорошо владею английским и прочесть информацию на сайте сложновато.